# How Can I Serve Static Content Alongside Dynamic Routes in A Deno Oak Server

Tags: javascript, routes, webserver, deno, oak

I am used to working with NodeJS and Koa. I've been playing with Deno and have run the example of a static fileserver:

```js
/* static_server.js */

import { Application } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts'

const port  = 8080

const app = new Application()

// Error handler middleware
app.use(async (context, next) => {
  try {
    await next()
  } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
})

// Send static content
app.use(async (context) => {
    console.log(`${context.request.method} ${context.request.url.pathname}`)
  await context.send({
    root: `${Deno.cwd()}/static`,
    index: "index.html",
  })
})


await app.listen({ port })
```

I have also created a dynamic server using routes:

```js
/* routes.js */

import { Application, Router } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts'

const port = 8080

const app = new Application()
const router = new Router()

router.get('/', context => {
    context.response.body = 'Hello world!'
  })

router.get('/foo', context => {
    context.response.body = 'Book Page'
  })

router.get('/foo/:thing', context => {
    context.response.body = `Foo ${context.params.thing}`
})

app.use(router.routes())
app.use(router.allowedMethods())

await app.listen({ port })
```

How can I combine these so that I can serve dynamic content but also provide static files such as the stylesheet?

In my Koa code I use the `koa-static` package:

```js
import serve from 'koa-static'
app.use(serve('public'))
```

What is the equivalent for an Oak server?

Adding suggested code (thanks Jonas Wilms)

```js
/* static_content.js */

import { Application, Router } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts'

const port = 8080

const app = new Application()
const router = new Router()

router.get('/', context => {
    context.response.body = 'Hello world!'
  })

router.get('/foo', context => {
    context.response.body = 'Book Page'
  })

router.get('/foo/:thing', context => {
    context.response.body = `Foo ${context.params.thing}`
})

router.get(context => context.send({ root: `${Deno.cwd()}/static` }))

app.use(router.routes())
app.use(router.allowedMethods())

await app.listen({ port })
```

but this still does not work...

Comment: `router.all(context => context.send({ root: .. }));` should work (as the last route).

Comment: Tried adding this but won't work. I'll try and post the current version of the code incorporating your suggestion.

Comment: What does "won't work" mean? Does the route match?

Comment: screen is blank and I get a 404 error.

Comment: May be this will help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62443440/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-os-error-2-in-deno/62446337#62446337

Answer (score 4):

After combining a lot of the information in the comments I managed to get things working:

```js
/* static_content.js */

import { Application, Router, Status } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts'

const port = 8080

const app = new Application()
const router = new Router()

// error handler
app.use(async (context, next) => {
  try {
    await next()
  } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
  }
})

// the routes defined here
router.get('/', context => {
    context.response.body = 'Hello world!'
})

router.get('/error', context => {
    throw new Error('an error has been thrown')
})

app.use(router.routes())
app.use(router.allowedMethods())

// static content
app.use(async (context, next) => {
    const root = `${Deno.cwd()}/static`
    try {
        await context.send({ root })
    } catch {
        next()
    }
})

// page not found
app.use( async context => {
    context.response.status = Status.NotFound
  context.response.body = `"${context.request.url}" not found`
})

app.addEventListener("listen", ({ port }) => console.log(`listening on port: ${port}`) )

await app.listen({ port })
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late on the thread, but there are some things I would like to point out.

In Oak 10.1 (the current version at the time of this writing), the `send` function throws an error if the file it tired to load did not exist.  Thus, our static+dynamic server can take on the following form.

```js
import { oak, pathUtils } from './deps.ts'

const app = new oak.Application()
const router = new oak.Router()

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
    try {
        await oak.send(ctx, ctx.request.url.pathname, {
            root: 'static',
            index: 'index.html',
        })
    } catch (_) {
        await next()
    }
})

router.get('/dynamic', ctx => {
    ctx.response.body = 'dynamic route worked'
})

app.use(router.allowedMethods())
app.use(router.routes())

app.listen({ port: 8000 })
```

If you want to serve your static files at a certain root path, change the static middleware so that it checks for the root and then omits that root path from the second argument of the `send` function.

```js
function staticMiddleware(rootPath: string, staticDirectory: string) {
    return async (ctx, next) => {
        if (!ctx.request.url.pathname.startsWith(rootPath)) return await next()

        const newPath = ctx.request.url.pathname.slice(rootPath.length)
        if (!newPath.startsWith('/') && newPath.length) return await next()

        try {
            await oak.send(ctx, newPath, {
                root: staticDirectory,
                index: 'index.html',
            })
        } catch (_) {
            await next()
        }
   }
}

app.use(staticMiddleware('/assets', 'static'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the static router at last. Because when use static server first, dynamic router is nonreachable for static router error.

```
app.use(router.routes())
app.use(router.allowedMethods())
// move the static router down
app.use( async context => {
  context.response.status = Status.NotFound
  context.response.body = `"${context.request.url}" not found`
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is still relevant or already outdated, but as of now (August 2022), there seems to be no general answer to this.

### Serving Static Files Alongside Your API Using Oak/Deno

When setting up OpenAPI for an `oak`-based REST service, I was coming across this issue as well. Requirements were:

- Serve `openapi.yml` statically from `/openapi/openapi.yml`
- Serve a HTML statically from `/openapi` for convenience
- Serve prefixed routers unaffectedly

A straight-forward approach to serve static files from a certain directory under a sub-path of the application is using a middleware and checking the path:

```js
import {
  Application, Context, Router
} from 'https://deno.land/x/oak@v11.1.0/mod.ts';

const app = new Application();
const port = 3000;

// Middleware only hooking in and sending static files if prefix matches
// the desired subpath:
const openapi = async (ctx: Context, next: () => Promise<unknown>) => {
  const prefix = '/openapi'; // Sub-path to react on
  if (ctx.request.url.pathname.startsWith(prefix)) {
    await ctx.send({
      root: `${Deno.cwd()}/src/openapi/`, // Local directory to serve from
      index: 'index.html',
      path: ctx.request.url.pathname.replace(prefix, ''), // Map to target path
    });
  } else {
    // If the request does not match the prefix, just continue serving from
    // whatever comes next..
    await next();
  }
};

// This is a dummy API endpoint wrapped into a prefixed router for demo:
const statusRouter = new Router({ prefix: '/status' });
statusRouter.get('/', (ctx: Context) => {
  ctx.response.body = {
    healthy: true,
    ready: true,
  };
});

// Boilerplate..
app.use(openapi);
app.use(statusRouter.routes());
app.use(statusRouter.allowedMethods());

app.addEventListener('listen', () => {
  console.log(`Listening on localhost:${port}`);
});

await app.listen({ port });
```

Running this MWE using `deno run --allow-net --allow-env --allow-read src/serve.ts`, you'll

- find the statically served `/openapi/openapi.yml`,
- find the `index.html` from your local static path served under `/openapi` (resp. `/openapi/` and `/openapi/index.html`)
- find the `/status` API behaving just normally.

Answer (score -1):

i'm using like that. In html you can provide a path to your file:

```html
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

then you can use routes to provide what do you want to use on path js/app.js:

```js
import {RouterContext} from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts'

const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8")// set doecoder
const fileCont = await Deno.readFile('./views/test.js') //getting file conetent
const fileJS = decoder.decode(fileCont) //decoding it

router.get('/js/app.js', (ctx: RouterContext) => { //yep, route can has defferents of real file location
        ctx.response.type = "application/javascript"
        ctx.response.body = fileJS
    })
```

and whatever you are providing this link somewhere it'll render you file.

Deno [REST API](https://github.com/Moranilt/deno-rest-api)